# Cómo editar el usuario pero si no ingreso la contraseña dejarla con la misma?

Tags: php7, laravel-6

con todos, literalmente lo que necesito es comparar mi contraseña actual con la que me viene en mi formulario de editar.
eh estado intentado esto en mi controllador

```
        $user=User::find($request->id); \\busca al usuario  

        password-old=Crypt::decrypt($user->password); \\desencriptar el passw. y almac.. en $pasw-old

        $checkPass=$request->password;      \\aqui almaceno mi password del formulario

        if ($checkPass==='')     \\aqui pregunto si $checkPass esta vacio
        {    
            $password=$password-old;  \\si es asi almaceno mi password antiguo     
        }else{
            $password=$request->password;   \\caso contrario almacene mi password nuevo
        }

        $users->password = $password;
```

ahora si bien es cierto Cryp::decrypt() no funciona porque mi password esta hasheado pero no sabria como hacerlo he aquí el dilema, espero esten bien y agradecere su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: no quiero encriptar mi clave en mi controllador ya que se hace en el model   lo traje a mi controllador para intentar desencriptar la contraseña    u busque al usuario por el id para traer su contraseña y compararla con el dato que envie a través de mi vista y de mi formulario de edicion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el detalle: Laravel no *encripta* tu contraseña al almacenarla, sino que la *hashea*. El *hashing* es un viaje en un solo sentido así que no hay manera simple de revertir el proceso (se puede hacer pero ya con técnicas avanzadas). Entonces, digamos que teóricamente no podrías recuperar la contraseña a partir del hash.

Lo que sí puedes comparar es que el hash de la contraseña a consultar para ver si es compatible con la que tienes almacenada. Esto lo realizas con el método `check()`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

// ...

public function myFunction()
{
    $oldPassword = User::find($id)->password; // esto es un hash
    $newPassword = request()->get('password'); // esto es texto plano

    $equals = Hash::check($newPassword, $oldPassword);

    if ($equals) {
        // Caso en el que las contraseñas son iguales..
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Debes registrar una contraseña que no hayas utilizado antes',
        ], 422);
    }

    // Caso en el que las contraseñas son distintas..
}
```

Pd: Como ejemplo estoy asumiendo que quieres actualizar la contraseña pero solo distinta a la que tienes actualmente. No entiendo muy bien el caso en sí que tratas de explicar, pero solo necesitas adaptar lo que puse arriba.

Comment: una consulta, ahí en el $newpassword   esta trayendo lo que ingrese en mi form osea 123456   y el hash::check  compara el 123456 con mi contraseña hasheada???

Comment: wooooooooo si Junciona Kenny  me devolvió true te ganaste tu like

Answer (score 0):

Te estas trayendo al usuario para editarlo.

```
$user = User::find($request->id); \\busca al usuario
```

Si cambia la contraseña:

```
$user->password = Hash::make($nueva_contraseña);
```

Si no cambia, simplemente no guardes la propiedad *password* de nuevo en el objeto `$user`, sería como hacer:

```
$user->password = $user->password;
```

***NOTA:*** la contraseña se "oculta" con `Hash::make()`, puedes verlo en el [RegisterController](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php) versión 6.x de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui traes la data que quieres guardar (es un ejemplo)
$data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'nickname', 'dni', 'role');

$password = $request->input('password');
if ($password) 
            $data ['password'] = bcrypt($password);